# If I don’t touch my plasma/lightning globe will it still produce ozone gas

Tags: ozone

I noticed when I touched my plasma/lightning globe that my fingertips smelled like what reminded me of ozone gas.
I read somewhere that ozone gas could be harmful to the respiratory system So I came to your site to find out information about this.
I quickly discovered that people are saying that they (plasma globes) do indeed produce ozone gas.
Then somebody wrote that only occurs when touching them since that causes the arcs of electricity to intensify.
My question is if I don’t touch my plasma globe can I leave it on for extended periods of time without creating ozone gas or such tiny amounts that there’s nothing hazardous to my health to be concerned about?

Comment: Poisonous as it is, ozone is more smelly than poisonous. If you don't smell it, there is no harm.

Comment: @BuckThorn, The stated answer in the duplicate Q provides no supporting references whatsoever and it is rather speculative (duplicated cut-paste answers circulating on the web).

Comment: @AChem Maybe someone can write a better answer to that post?

Comment: @BuckThorn, Hopefully so. Hard to find reliable and specific information on this topic. Google Scholar would be a good start if someone is interested. There is a J.Chem.Ed article on plasma globes which makes a generic comment and gives reference to a high-voltage engineering book, *First, any high-voltage source can produce toxic ozone gas; thus, prolonged operation of this device without adequate ventilation is not recommended*